# How to load a trained model's weights, which were saved with tf.keras.models.save_model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a neural network, without any checkpoints, and at the end I wrote `tf.keras.models.save_model(model, dirpath)` to save the whole model, which created the following files:

```
savedmodel.pb 
assets/
variables/variables.index
variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001
```

I tried loading the model using `new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(dirpath)`, but it gave a ValueError because I'm using a custom model (it seems, I created a class inheriting from `tf.keras.Model`). So instead I tried to instantiate a new model, and then just load the weights using

```
model = myModel(someArgs)
model.load_weights(dirpath/variables)
```

However, I get the following error message:

> OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'dirpath/variables', errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)

So how can I load the weights onto the model? The files are there I just don't know how to put them back inside my model.

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out, I was using the wrong path. I need to do `model.load_weights(dirpath/variables/variables)`. There ate two files called `variables`, with different extenstions (`.data-00000-of-00001` and `.index`), and that is the name you want to call.